# Find limit (without using L' Hospital Rule) I can find this limit using L' Hospital Rule, I do not know how to do it without that

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Find limit (don't use Lophital rule)
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}\:-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}\:}\right)$$

I can find this limit using L' Hospital Rule, I do not know how to do it without that.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have you ever seen a problem to "rationalise the surds", e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436856/42969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: put $\;a=\sqrt[3]{1+x}\;,\;\;b=\sqrt[3]{1-x}\;$ , then your eexpression is is

$$\frac{a^{3/2}-b^{3/2}}{a-b}=\frac{(a^{1/2}-b^{1/2})(a+a^{1/2}b^{1/2}+b)}{a-b}=\frac{a+a^{1/2}b^{1/2}+b}{a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}}$$